# Is there an easier way to add a horizontal scrollbar to a listbox in ASP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have done some looking and I found this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14439/The-ScrollableListBox-Custom-Control-for-ASP-NET-2

but to me it seems like there must be a simpler method.. with regular C# .NET you can just do

```
listbox1.HorizontalScrollbar = true;
```

and then your listbox comes up with one with no hassle, isn't there some simple way to apply one to an asp listbox in the same fashion?

Comment: Welcome to web development. Short answer, no - you will have to use css and possibly javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No>

HTML does not support that.

Comment: This answers my question that I asked, short sweet and to the point, Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The only way I know of would be to put the control in a smaller `div` (explicit height and/or width), with `overflow:auto` set;

Answer (score 1):

just create a div tag with the overflow set to auto, then set the width to what ever you want it at, and have the list box set to autosize = true. This way the div tag will show only the specified width, and make a scroll bar available if the list box is wider than the div tag.